# How to put each item of json array into it's own div

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

html:

```
<div class="myThing"></div>
<div class="myThing2"></div>
```

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $.getJSON('/test/getsubtopics.php', function(data) {
        $(".myThing").html(data.subtopic_id);
        $(".myThing2").html(data.subtopic_name);
     });   
});
```

I want to get every subtopic_id and subtopic_name in it's own .myThing and .myThing2 divs (respectively)

here's how my data is coming in from getsubtopics.php:

```
$subtopic_id = array();
$subtopic_name = array();

$find_forum_subtopics = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT id, subTopicName FROM forumSubTopics WHERE topicID='$forum_topic_id' ORDER BY listValue ASC");

    while ($find_forum_subtopics_row = mysqli_fetch_array($find_forum_subtopics)) {
        $subtopic_id[] = $find_forum_subtopics_row['id'];
        $subtopic_name[] = $find_forum_subtopics_row['subTopicName'];
    }

$arr = array("subtopic_id" => $subtopic_id, "subtopic_name" => $subtopic_name);
echo json_encode($arr);
```

According to console log here is what's coming back:

```
subtopic_id: Array[56]
0: "1"
1: "2"
2: "3"
3: "4"
4: "5"
5: "6"
6: "7"
7: "8"
8: "9"
9: "10"
10: "12"
11: "13"
12: "14"
13: "15"
14: "16"
15: "17"
16: "18"
17: "19"
18: "20"
19: "21"
20: "22"
21: "23"
22: "24"
23: "25"
24: "26"
25: "27"
26: "28"
27: "29"
28: "30"
29: "31"
30: "32"
31: "33"
32: "34"
33: "35"
34: "36"
35: "37"
36: "38"
37: "39"
38: "40"
39: "41"
40: "42"
41: "43"
42: "44"
43: "45"
44: "46"
45: "47"
46: "48"
47: "49"
48: "50"
49: "51"
50: "52"
51: "53"
52: "54"
53: "55"
54: "56"
55: "57"

subtopic_name: Array[56]
0: "So Glad To Have You!"
1: "What's New in the World of Marriage?"
2: "Feedback and Site Help"
3: "Companionship"
4: "Commitment"
5: "Communication"
6: "Selflesness"
7: "Respect"
8: "Forgiveness"
9: "Trust"
10: "Intimacy and Quality Time"
11: "Mood and Romance"
12: "Foreplay and Sex"
13: "Physical Appearance and Attraction"
14: "His Needs and Her Needs"
15: "Date Nights and Fun Ideas"
16: "Wife/Mother"
17: "Husband/Father"
18: "Pregnancy"
19: "Parenting"
20: "Children"
21: "In-Laws"
22: "Grandparenting"
23: "Blended Family"
24: "Military Marriages"
25: "Interracial/Intercultural/Interfaith Marriages"
26: "Long Distance Marriages"
27: "Aging Parents"
28: "Adoption"
29: "Friends/Ex's"
30: "Communication"
31: "Credit/Debt"
32: "Budgeting/Planning"
33: "Giving/Saving"
34: "Investing"
35: "Child SUpport/Alimony"
36: "Unemployment"
37: "Just Married"
38: "Depression"
39: "Stress"
40: "Illness/Disability"
41: "Infertility"
42: "Abortion"
43: "LGBT"
44: "Pornography"
45: "Abuse and Addiction"
46: "Separation"
47: "Divorce"
48: "Affairs/Adultery"
49: "Remarriage"
50: "Faith and Spirituality"
51: "Temptation"
52: "Lack of Intercourse"
53: "Drifting Aapart"
54: "Empty Nest"
55: "Losing a Loved One"
```

Comment: Can you post what `data` looks like in the response?

Comment: How does your data structure looks like.

Comment: updated to show data structure

Comment: How many `myThing`s will there be each time? Random amount?

Comment: @Danw -- Post the response you receive please. `console.log(data)` in your callback and post that.

Comment: @FastTrack it will be different each time

Comment: updated to show console log

Comment: @Danw check out my answer below...

Answer (score 0):

```
$.getJSON('/test/getsubtopics.php', function(data) {
    $.each(data, function (inData) {
        $.each(inData, function () {
            $("body").append('<div class="myThing">' + inData.subtopic_id + '</div>'); 
            $("body").append('<div class="myThing2">' + inData.subtopic_name + '</div>');  
        });             
    });
});
```

You need to loop through your `data` object using the jQuery `$.each` function. Then, just append a new `<div>` with the appropriate content on each iteration.

Comment: @Danw sorry, I just revised my answer - see above. I forgot an extra loop! You need to loop through each `object` then through the `objects` IN that `object`... PHEW! Does that work for you?

Comment: now getting this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '10' in subtopic_id - but this approach makes sense!

Comment: @Danw ok, I think I know a solution for that - I am heading home from work now, so I won't be able to take a look until tomorrow morning. Standby and I'll have your solution!

Answer (score 0):

You have to seperate arrays coming back in the response.The indexes should correspond given the php for the arrays (`.subtopic_id` and `.subtopic_name`). Then just change your code as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON('/test/getsubtopics.php', function (data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.subtopic_id.length; i++) {//i is current index for subtopic_id and subtopic_name
            $("body").append('<div class="myThing">' + data.subtopic_id[i] + '</div>')//get id by index
                .append('<div class="myThing2">' + data.subtopic_name[i] + '</div>'); //get name by index
        }
    });
});
```

Also it should be noted it will be quite a bit more efficient to write the loop like this, to minimize the amount you append to document.body

```
var html = "";//holds the html so far
for (var i = 0; i < data.subtopic_id.length; i++) {
    html += '<div class="myThing">' + data.subtopic_id[i] + '</div>';
    html += '<div class="myThing2">' + data.subtopic_name[i] + '</div>'; //get name by index
}
$("body").append(html);//append all the html at once
```

Answer (score 0):

Look this working example:

```js
//native JS for get the JSON
var getJSON = function(url, callback) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', url, true);
    xhr.responseType = 'json';
    xhr.onload = function() {
      var status = xhr.status;
      if (status == 200) {
        callback(null, xhr.response);
      } else {
        callback(status);
      }
    };
    xhr.send();
};

//you change this part for your json
getJSON('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos', function (err, data){createDivs(err, data);});

function createDivs(err, data) {
    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    $("#items").append('<div id="'+ data[i].id +'" class="itemClass">"'+  data[i].title +'"</div> <div class="rectangle" style="background-image:  url('+data[i].url+');"></div><br>');
    
    //just break after 10
    if(i == 10){
    break;
    }
    }
    
    }
```

```css
.itemClass{
    width:200px;
    height:40px;
    background:grey;
    color:white;
}

.rectangle{
    width:200px;
    height:100px;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="items"></div>
```